# ¿Por qué mis amigas dicen "listo" en vez de "lista" cuando están listas para ir?

Tags: adjetivos, género

He tenido la impresión de que debo de usar "lista" cuando me refiero a una mujer.  Por ejemplo:

> Ella está lista para ir.

Pero es común oír a mis amigas decir solo *listo* en este contexto.  ¿Por qué no dicen *lista*?

¿Cuándo puedo usar *lista*? ¿Si ella dice "estoy lista", sería femenino, verdad?  ¿O siempre es *listo*?

Comment: ¿Podrías decir, por favor, en qué país o zona lo oyes?

Comment: Ellas son de México. Y la mayoría de o cerca de Guadalajara.

Comment: They say that because "Listo" is like saying "Todo esta listo para irnos"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usado como "estar listo":

> - Chica hablando: "(yo) estoy lista"
> - Chico hablando: "(yo) estoy listo"

Si omites "estar", este verbo puede tener como [sujeto elípitico](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sujeto_el%C3%ADptico) dos cosas: La persona que habla o la propia acción que se estuviera llevando a cabo.

Siendo el sujeto la propia persona, es exactamente igual que como "estar listo", pero sin decir "estar".

> - Chica hablando: "[(yo) estoy] lista"
> - Chico hablando: "[(yo) estoy] listo"

Si el sujeto es la propia acción que termina, entonces no se usa el adjetivo como masculino o femenino, sino como neutro o universal, que es español es como el masculino, y en este caso quedaría como "listo".

> "[lo que estaba haciendo está] listo"

"Lo que estaba haciendo" sería el sujeto y "está" el verbo.

Comment: Si eres de otro país y también lo dices así, deja aquí un comentario diciéndolo, por favor.

Comment: Y es igual si ella dice solo "lista" (sin la palabra "estoy")?

Comment: Depende. Decir "lista" está perfecto, se entiende que omite "estoy", aquí en España las chicas también lo suelen decir así. Si una chica dice "listo", vendría de la frase "[lo que estaba haciendo ya está] listo"

Comment: Veo ahora que había entendido mal tu pregunta.

Answer (score 7):

### Español

Esto se está refiriendo al hecho de terminar algo. Por ejemplo supón que una persona termina con sus tareas/actividades el podría decir:

> ¡Listo!

Esto es como una version corta de:

> Esto está listo.

Lo que quiere decir es que ya terminó de hacer algo. Por eso se dice listo sin importar si el interlocutor es hombre o mujer.

---

### Inglés

This is referring to the fact that something has been finished. Suppose that a person just finished his tasks/duties he/she could say:

> ¡Listo!

This is like a short version of:

> Esto está listo.

What he/she wants to say is that he/she just finished something. That's why it is said "listo" regardless of the gender of the speaker.

Answer (score 1):

### Español

Usan "listo" como una expresión que significa en inglés "ok / Bien", " Esta pronto / hecho" o "entiendo" pero solo como una expresión que no se usa en todos los sitios. El uso correcto es que apunta JoulSauron en su respuesta:

> Chica hablando: "estoy lista"
>
> Chico hablando: "estoy listo"

---

### Inglés

They use "listo" as an expression meaning "ok" , "I'm ready" or "I understand" but just as an expression that is not used everywhere. The correct use is as JoulSauron pointed in his answer:

> Chica hablando: "estoy lista"
>
> Chico hablando: "estoy listo"

Comment: Es preferible siempre responder en español, especialmente si la pregunta está en ese idioma. Si no sabes muy bien español, puedes hacer un intento y luego poner tu respuesta en inglés, los hablantes nativos en castellano ya te corregirán. Los motivos los puedes leer aquí: http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/219/should-we-make-spanish-our-official-language 
http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/196/seeking-site-translators
Básicamente, ¡si no no vendrán expertos de español!

Comment: @JoulSauron, The person that asks speak english (his native language). I speak both English and Spanish (also Portuguese). so, don't worry next time I will use both languages. | La persona que hizo la pregunta habla en Ingles (idioma nativo). Yo hablo Español e Ingles (también Portugués), así que no te preocupes, la próxima vez usare los dos idiomas.

Comment: Thank you so much for your understanding. We really hope this helps to get experts of Spanish language.